# Universal Abelian Cover of a genus $g$ surface

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

Question 19 of Hatcher is given to be:

Use the preceeding problem to show that a closed orientable surface $M_g$ of genus $g$ has a connected normal covering space with a deck transformation group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ if and only if $n \leq 2g$.

To show that it holds for $n = 2g$, we simply observe that the 1-skeleton of a genus $g$ surface is given by $$X^1 = \bigvee_{\alpha =1}^{2g} S_{\alpha}^1.$$ Therefore, $\pi_1(M_g) = \pi_1(X^1) = \star_n \mathbb{Z}.$

Moreover, the previous problem in Hatcher allows us to conclude that the connected normal covering space has deck transformation group given by $$\pi_1(M_g)/[\pi_1(M_g),\pi_1(M_g)] = \star_{n}\mathbb{Z}/[\star_n \mathbb{Z}, \star_n \mathbb{Z}] \cong \mathbb{Z}^n.$$ I don't understand why the same holds for $n < 2g$, because this will alter the fundamental group $\pi_1(X^1)$ and consequentially the deck transformation group; since we are removing 2-cells.

Comment: The question is whether or not there's a quotient group of $\pi_1(M_g)$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^n$. And the answer is the same as whether there's a quotient group of $\pi_1(M_g)^{ab} = \Bbb Z^{2g}$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^n$.

Comment: Your computation of $\pi_1(M_g)$ is wrong; $\pi_1$ doesn't depend just on the $1$-skeleton; the 2-cells gives some relations.  Actually, for $M_g$, you have to deleted a single (well-chosen) disk from $M_g$ to obtain a deformation retraction onto its $1$-skeleton, and so $\pi_1(M_g)$ is equal to the free product of $2g$-copies of $\mathbb Z$, modulo a certain single relation (which surely must be discussed in Hatcher's text).

Comment: Indeed, page 51, just above Cor 1.27 that $M_g$ is not homeomorpic, or even homotopy equivalent, to $M_h$ for $h \neq g$.